# return const value for built-in type

Tags: c++, constants

Is it a good custom to return a const value for built-in type?

The reason is:

```
const int F()
{
}

int y;
F(x) = y;
```

The above code will not compile if the return value is const. However
if it's not, `F(x) = y;` is a very hidden mistake.

Since it has no meaning to assign a value to a function, I'm thinking
is it a good custom to always return a const value for built-in type?
If I always return a const value for built-in type, is there any problem?

Comment: IIRC, `F(x) = y` won't compile even without the `const` modifier because `F(x)` is not an lvalue.

Comment: For built-in's the const is effectively redundant. IT *used* to be good advice to, for user-defined types, return them as const to match this behavior. However with C++11 move-semantics, this ends up being a terrible idea. So never return a value as const. (Put another way, it's not really up to you to tell your caller if it can change its copy of the value.)

Comment: @fred where is the dupe? you are asking about a compiler bug. but this question asks something about c++. i really fail to detect the dupiness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` means that during the lifetime of an object, the value of the object does not change.

The Standard itself notes that hence, const does not make sense on prvalues of nonclass or nonarray prvalues. Such expressions never refer to objects (at least if the expression originates from user code. The language itself may create prvalues during reference binding which magically refer to temporary objects. IMHO, though, these should be xvalues instead). Hence since there is no object, there is no lifetime. And hence, there is nothing to be held "const".

Answer (score 3):

Assigning to a function call of this type isn't legal anyway. g++ gives me this error message if I try:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:8: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

So you don't need to also declare the return value `const` just to get a suitable diagnostic from the compiler.