# Unexpected return type when combining std::forward, std::move and volatile

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, decltype, trailing-return-type

*Code [on gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/4cfwFl).*

I created a simple type trait to remove rvalue references:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference<T&&> { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
using remove_rvalue_reference_t = 
    typename remove_rvalue_reference<T>::type;
```

I'm using it to implent a `copy_if_rvalue(x)` function whose return type depends on the passed argument:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto copy_if_rvalue(T && x) 
  -> remove_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x))>
{
    return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x);
}
```

To make sure the function returns the correct types, I've written some simple static assertions:

```
// literal
static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(copy_if_rvalue(0)), int
>{});

// lvalue
int lv = 10;
static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(copy_if_rvalue(lv)), int&
>{});

// const lvalue
const int clv = 10;
static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(copy_if_rvalue(clv)), const int&
>{});

// rvalue
int rv = 10;
static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(copy_if_rvalue(std::move(rv))), int
>{});

// volatile lvalue
volatile int vlv = 10;
static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(copy_if_rvalue(vlv)), volatile int&
>{});

// const lvalue
volatile const int vclv = 10;
static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(copy_if_rvalue(vclv)), volatile const int&
```

All the above static assertions compile successfully. When trying to `std::move` a `volatile int` variable, though, something unexpected occurs:

```
// volatile rvalue
volatile int vrv = 10;

// (0) fails:
static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(copy_if_rvalue(std::move(vrv))), volatile int
>{});

// (1) unexpectedly passes:
static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(copy_if_rvalue(std::move(vrv))), int
>{});

// (2) unexpectedly passes:
static_assert(std::is_same<
    remove_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(std::forward<decltype(vrv)>(std::move(vrv)))>, 
    volatile int
>{});
```

Assertion (0) fails - the `volatile` does not propagate, as demonstrated by assertion (1).

However, assertion (2) passes, even if I think it should be equivalent to assertion (0), since `copy_if_rvalue`'s return type is exactly the same as (2)'s first type:

```
// (from assertion (2))
remove_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(std::forward<decltype(vrv)>(std::move(vrv)))> 

// ...should be equivalent to...

// (from copy_if_rvalue)
-> remove_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x))>
```

It seems that `volatile` is not propagated only when `std::move` is used and only through the `copy_if_rvalue` template function.

What is going on here?

Comment: Simplified [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/992d1e5fe1aa931f) : (`const int foo();` `decltype(foo())` is `int`).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13155026/34509 . This doesn't only apply to `const`, but also to `volatile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no cv-qualified scalar prvalues. [[expr]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#6):

> If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`”, where `T` is a
>   cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression
>   is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

I.e. the same rule giving

```
int const f();
f() // <=
```

type `int` applies here as well. If you try some class type instead of `int` (e.g. `std::string`), you will get the expected types.

Comment: Thanks. This explains the unexpected assertion results. What's the rationale for this rule *(specifically, why does this only apply to scalar types)*?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Well, (at least in C++03) a prvalue of `const int` behaves just as a prvalue of type `int`, and treating it as one may ease analysis somewhere else. Of course, there is a difference for class types (think about const member functions), and there is a difference for arrays (cf. [core issue 1059](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1059)). The wording I quoted was added by [core issue 1261](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1261). Also, check out [core issue 1026](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1026) (which covers the "why").